# RAND_bytes always returns 0 in OpenSSL-FIPS mode

Tags: openssl, shared-libraries, fips

I am trying to understand why `RAND_bytes()` always returns 0 when used in OpenSSL FIPS mode. I am using OpenSSL-FIPS-2.0.9.

To enable FIPS mode, my code first makes a call to `FIPS_mode_set( 1 )`, defined in `openssl-1.0.2j/crypto/o_fips.c`. This ensures that FIPS mode is set. Thereafter if I make a call to `RAND_bytes()`, which internally triggers `FIPS_rand_bytes()` defined in `openssl-fips-2.0.9/fips/rand/fips_rand_lib.c` and it always returns 0 ( essentially no random bytes ).

On further debugging, I notice that "`fips_rand_meth`" is set to NULL, which I am unable to reason out.

I tried using a gdb and watching that value of this function pointer and where it could be set to a NULL but it turns out that it is set as 
`static RAND_METHOD *fips_rand_meth = NULL` in the beginning and thereafter it gets set to `fips_rand_meth = meth` in `FIPS_rand_set_method()`.

As suggested, I even tried checking the error code ( if any ) using `ERR_get_error()` call, immediately after calling `RAND_bytes()`. However, it returns 0 ( which suggests that there is no error ).

There is definitely some gap in my understanding this interaction of setting FIPS mode and then calling its APIs. It would be great if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure that FIPS_mode_set() is returning non-zero? It's not enough to call the method, it also has to return the value you passed in (i.e. 1).

Comment: Yes, it is returning non-zero

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RAND_bytes.html), an error code of 0 from RAND_bytes() indicates that the returned bytes are not cryptographically strong. So you're getting a return value of 0 (failure) and an error of 0 (bytes aren't cryptographically strong). Let me take a look at fips_rand_meth.

Comment: I'm suspicious that the "if (!fips_rand_bits)" statement in FIPS_rand_set_method() isn't resolving to true and you're skipping the meth assignments. Can you track what the fips_rand_bits value is doing? I think this should be zero here if you're running in FIPS mode.